Solving $\lim _{x\to +\infty \:}\left(\frac{1-e^x}{1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}}\right)$ = $+\infty$
Solving $\lim _{x\to +\infty \:}\left(\frac{1-e^x}{1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}}\right)$
I know that $\lim _{x\to \:+\infty \:}\left(1-e^x\right)$ = $-\infty$
And I thought that  $\lim _{x\to +\infty \:}\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}}\right)$ = $+\infty$ because $\lim _{x\to +\infty \:}\left(1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)$ = $0^+$.
I know that the second part is wrong but I don't know what I'm meant to do to get $-\infty$.

The second part is wrong. For a finite large $x$, $e^{1/x}$ is greater than $1$

@YvesDaoust it's less than 0

$1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}\approx 0^-$ as $x\to\infty$
Recall that $\exp(1/x)$ is a decreasing function $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

I tried to use the graph to solve the denominator. Should it have been $0^-$ because it approaches 0 in the fourth quadrant or is this approach wrong?

When $x$ approaches $+\infty$ , then ${1-e^{1/x}}$ approaches $0$ from the right.
Therefore the limit of ${1-e^{1/x}}$ is $0^{-}$ at $+\infty$ and not $0^{+}$
So the limit of $\dfrac{1}{1-e^{1/x}}$ is $-\infty$

Please use MathJax to format your mathematical expressions. Mostly put $  $ around what you have. If you want ^ to apply to more than one character use { }. $1-e^{1/x}$ is rendered  $1-e^{1/x}$

thx u m8 tried to use latex and couldn't make it work

I'm having trouble understanding how $1-e^{1/x}$ approaches 0 from the right, would it not be left graph-wise?
